# Difference between grow at and grow by?

Tags: grammar

> Export earnings are stipulated to grow at 8%, and foreign capital
> inflows are assumed to grow at 3.5%. This increase in the rate of
> foreign exchange availability.

I usually use grow by 10% as in "China will grow by 10% in 2020.", but is grow at 10% equivalent or not? Why? They seem to be used interchangeably on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put simply, "growing at" is followed by a rate - say ten percent a year, for example.  If no time period is specified, then it is implied.

To "grow by" some percent does not specify a length of time, but instead refers to a date or time by when the growth will occur.